# Responsive videos using oembed in Wordpress 4.2.x?

Tags: wordpress, video, oembed

Is it possible to make videos in WordPress 4.2.x responsive using the oEmbed shortcode? If not, are there better solutions than having to use some outdated plugin? I can hardly imagine that WordPress 4.1 and higher cannot place responsive content out-of-the-box since it has become so mobile-friendly!

I have searched and searched but have found nothing so far ... probably just not using the right search terms. I can hardly imagine that WordPress 4.1 and higher cannot place responsive content out-of-the-box since it has become so mobile-friendly!

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not answer your question, but I've just tried something that works by installing a plugin called [Advanced Responsive Video Embedder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/) and adding the following css:

```
 .embed-youtube {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     padding-bottom: 60%;
 }

 .embed-youtube iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

The Plug-in also has some really good options, like editing paramaters of the embed like so: `wmode=transparent  iv_load_policy=3  modestbranding=1  rel=0  autohide=1`

P.S.: `.embed-youtube` is the class name of the container div engendered by the plug-in..

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin called 'FitVids for WordPress' to make your youtube videos responsive.

You can use it like this:

```html
<div id="youtubevid">
  [youtube R-S9vXFVOnU]
</div>
```

Now you have to add this CSS selector to make it responsive using the plugin. Go to Appearance->FitVids and enter the id of the selector and save changes: `jQuery("#youtubevid").fitVids();`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin called "Responsive Media". It makes embedded media by oEmbed responsive out of the box.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-media/